# PHP $SITE_URL Messing

Tags: php

We are hosting a WordPress site on our own Windows server its working fine, but few days back realized that there is a PHP contact form which sends a PDF attachments with radio buttons, which works fine when it was Hosted on Godaddy, now the problem is radio buttons are not loaded cos I see the URL is

```
<img src=\"$SITE_URL/patientform/ckedimage.png\"/>
```

and the $site_url is

```
$SITE_URL="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

I think its pulling up the local server name,how do I set the Site URL as domain.com ?

whole code

```
<?php

$SITE_URL="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$cnt1=1;
foreach($caffinarr as $sympKey=>$sympVal6)
{
if(in_array($sympVal6, $caffinevalue))
        {

            $html .="<td><img src=\"$SITE_URL/patientform/ckedimage.png\"/>
            <td>$sympVal6 </td>";
        }
        else
        {
            $html .="<td><img src=\"$SITE_URL/patientform/uncheckedimage.png\"/>
            <td >$sympVal6</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code to

```
<?php

 $SITE_URL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$dir = "/patientform/ckedimage.png";
//echo $SITE_URL.$dir;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL.$dir; ?>" />
```

This is how your code would be:

```
<?php



 $SITE_URL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$dir = "/patientform/ckedimage.png";
$dir_uncheck = "/patientform/uncheckedimage.png";
//echo'<img src="'.$SITE_URL.$dir.'" />';

$cnt1=1;
foreach($caffinarr as $sympKey=>$sympVal6)
{
if(in_array($sympVal6, $caffinevalue))
        {

            $html ='<td><img src="'.$SITE_URL.$dir.'" />
            <td>'.$sympVal6.'</td>';
            echo $html;
        }
        else
        {
              $html ='<td><img src="'.$SITE_URL.$dir_uncheck .'" />
            <td>'.$sympVal6.'</td>';
            echo $html;

            ?>
```

Comment: I dont Think its going to work but let me check, i was looking for option if we can get domain.com

Comment: Your code was wrong and I fixed it, it will get your domain name and link to the image

Comment: still no luck I believe something is wrong here 

`$html .="<td width=\"25\"><img src=\"$SITE_URL/patientform/uncheckedimage.png\"/>`

Comment: It should work just fine , I tested here, please post your whole code,

Comment: Ohh you probally  are putting a <?php tag inside another like <?php  <?php   ?>   ?> so it's just fix the tags

Comment: let me paste the whole code, It was working fine on Godaddy as soon as we came to Windows server we get PDF as attachement but insead of radio check boxes which are images it loads a red X mark.

please see the whole code in question.

Comment: Done I was offline , but I made the edits now it should work just fine, please if it solved your problem mark the answer as right and give a upvote

Comment: https://notepad.pw/iopwlf1f

All the codes I have remove credentials and smtp for security

Comment: add the full project to a zip file, maybe it's another file causing it

Comment: ok, but dont you think its Windows IIS server might be causing issue? is there anything we can allow in PHP to accept .png or JPG?

Comment: Why you are adding the whole html in a $html var? Your code is really messing, I will try to fix and add the the answer again.